# Getting a saddle rail back in

Tags: saddle

I have a saddle rail that has popped out.

Does anyone know how to get it to go back in?

[image: saddle rail popped out]

Comment: Pry, using whatever seems to work.  Flex the plastic seat base back, and simultaneously use Vice Grips or whatever to flex the rail forward.  And maybe a screwdriver wedged between to pry.  Might require 4 hands.  (I have seen this situation fixed a few times, but, depending on the condition of the seat, it may or may not be worth the effort.)

Comment: If its a steel rail then there is an elastic limit.  That is, you can bend the flat bit of the rail a little using a crowbar against the other one.  Exceed the limit and the rail becomes permanently bent, making the clamp hard to adjust, rail is weaker, and now its more likely to pop out again.   At that point its buy a new saddle.

Comment: I'd buy a new saddle.  To get the rail back in, you're going to have to stretch/bend the saddle material and/or bend the rail, likely making it even more likely for the rail to pop out again.  And it's already popped out once...

Answer (score 3):

Your only option is judicious application of force.

I'd find a way to clamp the saddle down with the nose up against an immovable object, then push the end of the rail forward with something until it clears the lug and can be slipped down and back into it's hole.

Using a length of 2x4 wood held somewhat like a handlebar may be effective at allowing you to push the end of the rail with enough force.

Comment: The only thing I’d add to this excellent answer is that a bit of heat can help the process. If it’s a warm sunny day, leave the seat in the sun until it’s nice and hot. If it’s cloudy or cold, then a hair dryer very carefully applied can warm it up. Be careful you don’t melt it!

Comment: @RoboKaren I was thinking of bending the rail rather than the plastic saddle body, but I think you're right that that plastic can be deformed mare easily.  Maybe placing something about a 1/2 inch high under the middle of the saddle to enable the back side to be bent downwards as the rail is pushed forwards

Comment: I’ve had the rail pop out of my cheap MTB saddle. You have to bend both the rail and the seat a bit. Heating the seat allows the rail to squiggle a bit more.

Comment: I did this once - it came down to a small pressure ridge around the end of the saddle rail.  Once I filed that flat and sanded then it moved in with all the brute force I could muster.